# How to use AVAudioPlayer to play a playlist in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, avaudioplayer, avfoundation

Please I know how to play a sound in AVAudioPlayer but I would like to know how to give it a list of on-disk files to play one after the other (play list)

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manage this by yourself, using the '`audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`' method to know when the current song is over, and when to start a new one.

Comment: yes, it is a delegate method so you would just have to implement that delegate protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The Apple "AddMusic" sample program does exactly this, setting up a playlist of audio files using MPMusicPlayerController and AVAudioPlayer to do most of the work.